# Creating new discord embed fields with array.length

Tags: javascript, arrays, embed, discord.js

So I have have an array of names `let namelist = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5'];` and i have a for loop that when a user uses the command `$list ame` it sorts through the array and grabs any element that has 'ame' in it and pushes them into a new array `temparray`.
My question is how can I make an embed that will grab temparray.length and make a new field for each string in the array?

I've tried using a for loop and a do...while() loop but I can't seem to figure out how to access the embed so i can use addField inside a loop. Is it possible to do that and/or is there a better way I can add a new line for each array element?
This is the code I have for the embed without the loops. I want to get rid of those .addFields and put them in a loop for automation

```
if(typeof args[0] === 'string' && args[0].length >= 3){
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor("Names containing " + "'" + `${args[0]}` + "'" )
    .addField(temparray[0], `this is ${temparray[0}` )
    .addField(temparray[1], `this is ${temparray[1}`)
    .addField(temparray[2], `this is ${temparray[2}`)
    .addField(temparray[3], `this is ${temparray[3}`)
    .addField(temparray[4], `this is ${temparray[4}`)
    .setColor("#92BA2F")
    .setThumbnail(bot.user.avatarURL)
    .setTimestamp(Date.now())
    message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, just `.addField()` on the embed variable in the loop.

```
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setAuthor("Names containing " + "'" + `${args[0]}` + "'" )
  .setColor("#92BA2F")
  .setThumbnail(bot.user.avatarURL)
  .setTimestamp(Date.now());
temparray.forEach(entry => {
  embed.addField(entry, 'looped field');
});
message.channel.send(embed);
```

You don't need to use the length of your array for this, but if you wanted to, you can use `for (let i = 0; i < temparray.length; i++)`.

Comment: The step should be *less than* the array length in the classic `for` loop, since one is zero-based and the other is not. `for (let i = 0; i < temparray.length; i++)`

Comment: @slothiful thanks! I'll edit that in - I'm always wrong about for loop checking!